# Hover state stuck on buttons after click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I have a form with two states: editing and visible.  When you click an icon to edit the form two buttons (acting like submit) at the bottom appear to save or cancel.  When I click them the form is updated (or cancelled) and the buttons disappear. The problem is when I re-open the form to edit it (and the buttons are visible again) the last one clicked still has it's hover state applied in Chrome.

```
       <div>
          <div class="col-xs-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="save(true)">Save</button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-5 cancel-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

For simplicity here is just the cancel function...

```
   $scope.cancel = function() {
      //set a flag for angular to hide/show editing mode in HTML
      $scope.editMode = false;
   };
```

Comment: Please post your complete code, the JS or CSS used to hide / show the buttons is missing so we can not properly help.

Comment: A fiddle will help understand problem better.

Comment: It's probably an active/focused state, not the hover state. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in an earlier comment (runTarm), this is because of the active/focused state of the buttons.

**To change it :**

```
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:focus {
  // place your 'default' styling over here
}
```

You will probably need to be more specific with your declaration because what I posted will override all the items with class `btn-primary`.

Hope this helps !